# Access mysqli database and pull up specific modules based on the data retrieved

Tags: php, mysql, module, joomla3.0

Could somebody please take a look at this code and see what errors I have. I am accessing user information from the mysql database, and based on certain values appearing in their individual data, I would like to get certain modules to appear. I am uploading this to Flexi custom module on Joomla (a custom module that holds any php code). It says that I am accessing the sql database correctly but isn't pulling up any of the modules based on the search queries.

```
//Skillfolio Custom Minifeed Document
//This doc should do a search to see what values appear in each users jos_social_fields_data 
//for the checkboxes they selected to choose what blog category would appear on their
//homepage. Then, for each value that does exist (the value assigned to the category), 
//the specific blog-category-minifeed is rendered.


<?php

$con = mysqli_connect("*****", "*****", "*****", "*****");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
 echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 }

//Importing ALL category modules up front, echo them following each sql fetch

jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$moduleart = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'ArtsARRA');
$moduleavi = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'AviationARRA');
$modulebus = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'BusinessARRA');
$modulecul = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'CulinaryARRA');
$moduleecon = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'EconomicsARRA');
$moduleedu = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'EducationARRA');
$moduleeng = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'EngineeringARRA');
$moduleent = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'EntertainmentARRA');
$modulefash = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'FashionARRA');
$modulehealth = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'HealthcareARRA');
$modulehist = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'HistoryARRA');
$modulelaw = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'LawARRA');
$modulemath = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'MathARRA');
$moduleoth = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'OtherARRA');
$modulephilo = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'PhilosophyARRA');
$modulepoli = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'PolisciARRA');
$modulepsych = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'PsychARRA');
$modulerel = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'ReligionARRA');
$modulesales = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'SalesARRA');
$modulescience = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'ScienceARRA');
$moduletech = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'TechARRA');
$moduleweb = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'WebDevARRA');
$modulewrite = JModuleHelper::getModule('arraarticles', 'WritingARRA');


//Later on after each SQL fetch: echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($modulename);


$sqlarts = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE         '%MINIARTS%'";

while ($rowarts = mysqli_fetch_array($sqlarts))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($moduleart);
}


$sqlaviation = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINIAVIATION%"';

while ($rowaviation = mysql_fetch_array($sqlaviation))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($moduleavi);
}

$sqlbusiness = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINIBUSINESS%"';

while ($rowbusiness = mysql_fetch_array($sqlbusiness))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($modulebus);
}

$sqlculinary = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINICULINARY%"';

while ($rowculinary = mysql_fetch_array($sqlculinary))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($modulecul);
}

$sqlecon = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINIECON%"';

while ($rowecon = mysql_fetch_array($sqlecon))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($moduleecon);
}

$sqled = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINIEDUC%"';

while ($rowed = mysql_fetch_array($sqled))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($moduleedu);
    }

$sqleng = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINIENGIN%"';

while ($roweng = mysql_fetch_array($sqleng))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($moduleeng);
}

$sqlent = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINIENTERTAINMENT%"';

while ($rowent = mysql_fetch_array($sqlent))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($moduleent);
}

$sqlfash = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINIFASHION%"';

while ($rowfash = mysql_fetch_array($sqlfash))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($modulefash);
}

$sqlhealth = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINIHEALTH%"';

while ($rowhealth = mysql_fetch_array($sqlhealth))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($modulehealth);
}

$sqlhistory = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINIHISTORY%"';

while ($rowhistory = mysql_fetch_array($sqlhistory))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($modulehist);
}

$sqllaw = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINILAW%"';

while ($rowlaw = mysql_fetch_array($sqllaw))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($modulelaw);
}

$sqlmath = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINIMATH%"';

while ($rowmath = mysql_fetch_array($sqlmath))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($modulemath);
}

$sqlphilo = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINIPHILO%"';

while ($rowphilo = mysql_fetch_array($sqlphilo))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($modulephilo);
}

$sqlpoli = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINIPOLISCI%"';

while ($rowpoli = mysql_fetch_array($sqlpoli))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($modulepoli);
}

$sqlpsych = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINIPSYCH%"';

while ($rowpsych = mysql_fetch_array($sqlpsych))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($modulepsych);
}   

$sqlreligion = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINIRELIG%"';

while ($rowreligion = mysql_fetch_array($sqlreligion))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($modulerel);
}

$sqlsales = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINISALES%"';

while ($rowsales = mysql_fetch_array($sqlsales))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($modulesales);
}

$sqlscience = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINISCIENCE%"';

while ($rowscience = mysql_fetch_array($sqlscience))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($modulescience);
}

$sqltech = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINITECH%"';

while ($rowtech = mysql_fetch_array($sqltech))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($moduletech);
}

$sqlweb = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINIWEB%"';

while ($rowweb = mysql_fetch_array($sqlweb))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($moduleweb);
}

$sqlwriting = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%MINIWRITING%"';

while ($rowwriting = mysql_fetch_array($sqlwriting))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($modulewrite);
}

$sqlother = 'SELECT * FROM jos_social_fields_data WHERE data LIKE "%other%"';

while ($rowother = mysql_fetch_array($sqlother))
{
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($moduleoth);
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: remove ip adresses and passwords!!

Comment: shouldn't you be telling us what errors you have?

Comment: You're setting the different variables for the query, but never actually executing the it. Note also that many of your statements refer to `mysql_fetch_array()`, but should use `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Comment: @Dagon, I am not receiving any errors on my page, it just isn't pulling up the modules that I am requesting via the code.

Comment: @Mike W... how do I execute it? Sorry if that is a basic question, I have developed softwares using C and webpages using html & css, but I am new to PHP.

Comment: Also @MikeW, I was testing this on my site just using $sqlarts which does utilize mysqli_fetch_array(), and is structured slightly differently than the items following it. Once I have the proper structure I will apply it to the rest of the items and hopefully be able to implement it

Comment: It looks like you have about 10 or so queries that are processed in nearly identical ways. Consider collapsing them down into a loop, to simplify things.

Comment: I do have everything expanded right now until I figure out the proper code that will actually get the desired results, then I will likely condense it with a loop.

Comment: @Ashley There's too much going on here to answer succinctly. You're assigning a load of variables at the top of your code that you don't seem to use, but then use a different method later. You need to establish that you can include the modules that you need based on some simple debugging code, then worry about your database queries. I'm voting to close because it's not clear exactly what you need help with

Comment: The variables that I am assigning at the top are used in each of the sql queries. Each variable corresponds to a minifeed that I created, and each search query "should" result in displaying the corresponding minifeed (each minifeed displays posts from a specific blog category, i.e. arts).

@MikeW.. The users on my site subscribe to specific blog categories that are saved in their sql data. That is why I am trying to run the sql queries, so that based on their data, ONLY the specific blog minifeed that they have subscribed to will appear on their homepage. I hope that clears up my goals.